# Recuperar URL digitada

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema que utiliza `Session` que expira com inatividade. O acesso a arquivos no sistema, só é liberado após abertura da sessão. Até aí beleza, está funcionando. Gostaria de memorizar o link que foi digitado na URL do navegador (barra de endereços) por exemplo http://sistema.empresa.com.br/public/anexo/documentox.pdf. Fiz um código aqui, mas ele não me retorna para o resultado esperado. Retorna até a pasta "public". Teria que armazenar na variável $url_browser, a string exata da barra de endereços. Segue o código.

```
 $url_browser = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 //aqui executa o processo de login...
 header('Location: ' . $url_browser);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode tentar :

```
 $url_browser = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 //aqui executa o processo de login...
 header('Location: ' .$url_browser);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Seta em uma variável assim:

```
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.